# Ways of implementing timer in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c

What are some of the better/best ways of implementing a countdown timer in iOS?

I've done some digging and tried using NSTimers (1 sec timer) but some people suggest that's not a good way because its not very accurate!!!  Others claim it wastes battery, since its always going to be on in the background till the time elapses.  I was thinking I could create a multiple scheduled NSTimer so it won't loose sync.  Some suggest I should record the actual timestamp at the beginning and somehow make use of the built-in clock and use that to update the timer countdown.... except I can't seem to figure out how to do that.  Any ideas?  How are you implementing it?

Answer (score 5):

Any time you are implementing a timer, the best option is always to record your start time. Then, whenever you update your interface, simply take the difference of the current time and your start time. You can then use NSTimers to trigger updates of the interface at certain periods.

Comment: +1: This also allows the timer to be resumed accurately if the user quits and then restarts the app (if such a feature is desired).

Comment: This makes a lot of sense and simplifies things.  Thanks.

Comment: In such case I would recommend to save the start time with a timezone. Anyways this approach will not work if user changes time settings manually. Maybe using "system time" has no such flaws.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, `NSTimer`s are not very accurate. So you should typically not simply multiply the time-interval you specified with the fire-count, but instead use some sort of time-stamp (e.g. a stored `NSDate` should work fine for your needs).

Regarding the battery drain, I strongly doubt that a timer with an interval in the the frequency domain of ~1 Hz has any *measurable* effect. And if I'm not completely mistaken, when your application enters the background, all timers will be paused and rescheduled with their respective fire-date, when the app re-enters to the foreground — so no harm here, either.

Comment: Reports of NSTimer's inaccuracy are greatly exaggerated, IMHO. It should be absolutely fine for updating the interface once a second. It's only when you are relying on it in the range of tens and ones of milliseconds that you may have a problem.

Comment: @Josh Caswell depends: I've seen it behave pretty jumpy on a simple one second timer. (Although that was in a capture-application on the Mac.)

Comment: Hmmm... I guess I'll just have to experiment with it.  It will also depend on hardware although from a hardware perspective, I find it hard that a 1GHz CPU cannot service 1 sec timers within reasonable time.  Unless there's just alot of stuff happening thats needs service.... which then begs the question how does Apple implement their Timer and StopWatch without any of these issues???

Comment: @HM1 Well the hardware totally can do _much_ better. `NSTimer` just isn't meant to be real-time. It will fire after a certain amount of time has passed when its runloop enters one of the modes, the timer was scheduled for. If the iteration through the runloop took longer, then the callback happens with that delay. That's all. In your case of a 1Hz countdown, a 2-10Hz `NSTimer` in conjunction with a saved start date should work just fine.